# Can't use objective C statements/data types in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to use a class in Objective C in my Swift project, I've added the dependency "-ObjC" in my linker flag and also used the bridging header. Basically all the other Objective C classes and library works except for this one.

[image]

Comment: NSColor is on Mac OSX, not on iOS. Its "equivalent" is UIColor.

Comment: That's probably worthy of an answer @Larme

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSColor` is a on *Mac OS X*, not on *iOS*.
Its "equivalent" is `UIColor`.

That's why the compiler says that it doesn't know `NSColor`.

Comment: can I use UIColor instead of NSColor or is there significant difference between the two?

Comment: They have some methods that are the same, but not all are the same. So depending on if the code use specific ones...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

Hope this helps.